# Using defer inside if

Tags: swift

I want to execute some code after the function exits only if some code succeed like this:

```
if object.open {
    defer {
        object.close()
    }
}
...
dome some stuff...
...
return
}
```

The problem is that the defer is executing right after the if condition. As I understand that is the correct behavior.

The question then is: ***It is possible to defer a code of block inside the if to run after the function complete.*** 
I tried nested defers but that did not work.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not `defer { if object.open { object.close() } }`?

Comment: Does “doing some stuff” require that the object has been opened successfully?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the abstract example what your actual use case is, but it would indeed seem like you should probably `guard` against the object failing to open and then `defer` the closing only for the cases where it is open. Or if it is always open but may become closed due to some exceptional situation, threat those paths that close it early as special cases. (Or if you also implemented `object`, allow `close()` of an already-closed object as a harmless NOP.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using `defer`, it is not possible to directly defer something to happen beyond the end of the current scope, e.g., that of the `if` condition you are in. It is possible, however, to defer something unconditionally and move the condition inside the `defer`:

```
defer {
    if object.isOpen { object.close() }
}
```

A more general solution along these lines would be something like this:

```
var deferred: (() -> Void)? = nil
defer { deferred?() }
if object.isOpen {
    deferred = { object.close() }
}
```

This more general solution would allow deferring different things based on different conditions, but obviously at most one at a time. To support more than one you could of course use an array:

```
var deferred = [(() -> Void)]()
defer {
    for f in deferred.reversed() { f() }
}
if object1.isOpen {
    deferred.append { object1.close() }
}
if object2.isOpen {
    deferred.append { object2.close() }
}
```

**However, I strongly advise against this** as it obfuscates the code flow and seems indicative of bad design elsewhere. Usually the reason to use `defer` is when you have multiple ways out of a scope and want to avoid copypasting the same clean-up code to all of them, but here you have multiple paths through the clean-up. I would try to isolate the paths leading to the different clean-up requirements.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html):

> A defer statement is used for executing code just before transferring program control outside of **the scope that the defer statement appears in**.

So, to answer your question:

> It is possible to defer a code of block inside the if to run after the function complete.

No. `defer` runs whenever its enclosing scope ends.